# simple tutorial on how to use SQLite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I'm using VB.NET and Microsoft SQL Server 2005 to create an application. I was told I should use SQLite instead, as I want my application to be standalone with an embedded database. Can someone please provide me with a step-by-step tutorial on how to create a standalone application with an embedded database?

Sorry, I'm quite new to this. Thanks for reading and answering.

Comment: http://www.kwoxer.de/2014/09/25/sqlite-datenbank-in-vb-net-erstellen-und-nutzen/ SQLite in 1 min (Tutorial in German)

Comment: @kwoxer please put your answer in an answer so that it can be accepted/upvoted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This website looks fairly promising:

https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/index.php?showtopic=157830

Answer (score 11):

Here is a quick tutorial: [SQlite on .NET in three minutes](https://web.archive.org/web/20100208133236/http://www.mikeduncan.com/sqlite-on-dotnet-in-3-mins/)